How to resolve "Cannot open include file: 'opencv2/opencv.hpp' No such file or directory" in Visual Studio Community 2022?
I am getting the above error after installing opencv and making changes in Visual Studio in,
project properties->Configuration Properties->C/C++->General->Additional include Directories =>E:\opencv\build\include
project properties->Configuration Properties->Linker->General->Additional Library Directories =>E:\opencv\build\x64\vc16\lib
project properties->Configuration Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies =>opencv_world4100.lib,opencv_world4100d.lib
Project Properties->platform =>x64

I am getting the same error even after installing opencv by vcpkg package manager as well.
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    cv::Mat image = cv::imread("C:/Users/Admin/Downloads/muruga.jpg");
    if (image.empty()) {
        std::cerr << "Error: Unable to load image!" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    cv::imshow("Image", image); // Display the image
    cv::waitKey(0);             // Wait for a key press
    return 0;
}

The issue got resolved now when I built the solution in Release mode but I am getting the same error when I built the solution in Debug mode. Does anyone know why?

project properties -> Configuration Properties - which configuration are you tuning and which configuration are you building?

There are separate configurations for each kind of build (Release, Debug, or any custom one you may create). Make sure Additional include Directories are set identically for all.

Did you use a vcpkg (build in package manager) to add OpenCV to your project?
